# Locate an element based on another element xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to automate a process using selenium and a webdriver.

The html looks like this:

```
<span class="contract-item">
    <span class="contract-label">
        <span class="contract-name">Jimmy</span>
    </span>
    <div class="current-stats">
        <span class="info"></span>
```

The issue I am facing is that there are many 'contract-item' and 'info' classes. I only want to find info for specific 'contract name's. However by finding the 'contract name' I have lost the info. How do I get the 'info' for a specific name?

I have this so far.

```
team_name = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), {})]".format(jimmy))[1]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Consider re-titling. You wish to find the *element* (not "shell") containing text (and it really doesn't matter how you came by the HTML -- scraped or otherwise).

Comment: @PartialOrder I have one element and to get the element I am looking for I need to get the shell of the one I have.

Comment: Yes. Understood. Elements can be nested.

Comment: Your html is invalid; the first `span` and the `div` don't have closing tags. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get the element that contains the name, you did that correctly

```
//*[contains(text(), "{}")]
```

Then you need to go the nearest common parent between the info element and the element you found, each `/..` will go one element up the HTML tree.

```
//*[contains(text(), "{}")]/../..
```

Finally, find the correct element filtering by class

```
//*[contains(text(), "{}")]/../..//span[@class="info"]//text()
```

So, you expression should be :

```
team_name = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "{}")]/../..//span[@class="info"]//text()'.format('jimmy'))[1]
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Below is required xpath:

> //*[@class='contract-item' and
>   contains(.,'Jimmy')]/div/span[@class='info']

You just need to change the contact name String (i.e. Jimmy) with desired one and you will get corresponding info.